# Facebook App stream not always showing

Tags: facebook, post, stream

I just created a new Facebook App. But when we test it, it doesn't always show the stream post. Sometimes it works, but when i remove the app from my personal Facebook and try it again it doesn't show the stream post again. Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Kind Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

When you reauthorise the app, do you ask for `read_stream` extended permission? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: @MarkdeHooge If that's the answer you were looking for, then select it as an answer. : )